# Why javascript has two tags bracket instead one like link?

Tags: javascript

Probably it's a stupid question but why I can write:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myStyle.css" />
```

But if I want incluse javascript file I must use this:

```
 <script src="jquery-1.11.js"></script>
```

Instead of

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.js" />
```

Comment: The rule of thumb is that any element that _can_ contain something should have an open and close tag, not a self-closing tag. `<script>` can contain content, hence why you see the open and close tags.

Comment: Little more clarification please.

Comment: `<link>` is a self closing tag. When you typ `<script>`, a script is expected.

Comment: @user45763 `<script>...</script>`

Comment: `script` tag can contain code. Since it can contain something, it's not a self closing tag. `link` on the other hand can only have attributes and properties but not content

Comment: And, for logic I'll never follow, *inline stylesheets* use the `<style>` tag, not `<link>`. That tag must use a closing tag.

Comment: Surely self-closing `<script/>` tags *do* work in an XHTML document.

Comment: `<script … />` would be technically valid in XHTML, but Internet Explorers (at least older versions) mess up badly when this is used – they treat the following elements as _content_ of the script element, instead of as separate, independent elements.

Comment: @CBroe ah I should have said "do work in functional browsers working with XHTML" :) Also of course not many XHTML pages are really interpreted as XHTML anyway, due to botched content type etc.

Comment: Somebody had linked a duplicate in a comment, but it's gone. The real answer is that the self-closing syntax in HTML is meaningless. It's allowed by the parser but it has absolutely no effect.